# Access to Thunderbird Address Book - abook.mab

Tags: excel, vba, thunderbird

I have an Excel VBA macro where I send emails using Thunderbird. I would like to know if there's a way to access Thunderbird's address book so that I could search an email adress from a textbox. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

According to this documentation, the Thunderbird MAB files are in a format called "MORK":
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Address_Book

Here is info on the MORK format, with some links to Python scripts and other code which you may be able to deconstruct and convert to VBA:
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mork